# MySQL auto populate number field base on another field

Tags: mysql

mysql question... So I would like to auto populate a number, but I would like it to be based on another field. I'm not sure how to explain it other than using this example:

```
Field 1 | Field 2 (auto populate)
   1    |   1
   2    |   1
   2    |   2
   2    |   3
   3    |   1
   3    |   2
   2    |   4
   2    |   5
```

Is there a mysql function expression that can be added to the column?

I know I could do this in my Python script that is feeding the values, but I have to assume it will be faster if the function is baked into mysql.

**UPDATE:** 
Let me add some clarification...

Field 1 will get filled with a value from a script.

There will be multiple entries of Field 1 that are the same number.

I would like Field 2 to auto populate to have a unique number WITHIN that Field 1 number.

Comment: Auto populate how? What is the relation between Field 1 and 2?

Comment: You want to automatically enter a number in the column, may be random?

Comment: @GurV added some clarification.

Comment: @LeonardoRamosDuarte no random. It would be best if it auto-populated up from 1 (or 0)

Comment: Do the rows in  'Field 1' exist already, or would the values in 'Field 2' be auto-populated in real time? Also, is there a pre-existing PRIMARY KEY? Finally, also, consider whether this is really something that needs to be stored instead of simply being calculated 'on-the-fly'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a trigger which is a function which automatically runs on certain conditions.
Here is the manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html.
You could for example use a `AFTER UPDATE` or `AFTER INSERT` trigger for this purpose.

Comment: Yes. I think this is what I'm looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can just store the field1 and generate field2 as increasing integer value within each field1 using user variables like this:

```
select
    t.field1,
    @rn := if(field1 = @f1, @rn + 1, if(@fi := field1, 1, 1)) field2
from (
    select
        t.*
    from your_table t
    order by field1   --very important
) t cross join (select @rn := 0, @f1 := -1) t2
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html). Something like the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `populate_field_2` BEFORE INSERT ON `table_name` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE _new_val INT DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT MAX(field_2)+1 INTO _new_val FROM 'table_name' WHERE field_1 = NEW.field_1;
    SET NEW.field_2 = _new_val;
END
```

This would populate field_2 each time you created a new row. You can update the logic to create whatever value for field2 you need.

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside the usual caveats relating to MyISAM tables...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(field1 INT NOT NULL 
,field2 INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
,PRIMARY KEY(field1,field2)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;

INSERT INTO my_table (field1) VALUES
(1),(2),(2),(2),(3),(3),(2),(2);

SELECT * FROM my_table;

+--------+--------+
| field1 | field2 |
+--------+--------+
|      1 |      1 |
|      2 |      1 |
|      2 |      2 |
|      2 |      3 |
|      2 |      4 |
|      2 |      5 |
|      3 |      1 |
|      3 |      2 |
+--------+--------+
```

..but I would question whether there's really any sense storing this information at all...

...hence, a more robust approach...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(field1 INT NOT NULL 
,field2 INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO my_table (field1) VALUES
(1),(2),(2),(2),(3),(3),(2),(2);

SELECT x.field1
     , CASE WHEN @prev = field1 THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END i 
     , @prev:=field1 prev
  FROM my_table x
     , (SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars
 ORDER
    BY field1
     , field2;

+--------+------+------+
| field1 | i    | prev |
+--------+------+------+
|      1 |    1 |    1 |
|      2 |    1 |    2 |
|      2 |    2 |    2 |
|      2 |    3 |    2 |
|      2 |    4 |    2 |
|      2 |    5 |    2 |
|      3 |    1 |    3 |
|      3 |    2 |    3 |
+--------+------+------+
```